# Reach destination with minimum energy at start

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given N points in a straight line with distance from origin. Also we are provided the end point where we need to reach. Now to be at ith point we should be having X[i] amount of energy and also that point will give Y[i] amount of profit as energy that is being added. Now we need to find out how much minimum energy we should start with so as to reach destination point after starting from origin.

**Example :** Let we have 5 points and destination point is at 10 units from origin.

Then let us say first point is at 1 unit from origin , require 2 units of energy and gives profit of 3 unit.

Second point is at 2 unit from origin , require 3 units of energy and gives profit of 0 unit.

Third point is at 4 unit from origin , require 3 units of energy and gives profit of 5 unit.

Fourth point is at 8 unit from origin , require 5 units of energy and gives profit of 0 unit.

Fifth point is at 9 unit from origin , require 1 units of energy and gives profit of 2 unit.

Now answer for this configuration is 6.

**Explanation :**

Because say if we start with 5 units of energy then

At point 1, we have more than or equal to 2 units of energy, hence the profit 1 adds to the energy and total energy is 6.

At point 2, three units of energy would be gone leaving 3 only 3 units.

At point 3, since the energy is exactly 3, the profit will be added and total energy becomes 5.

At point 4, all 5 units will be gone and we cant move ahead

Similarly, if we start with 6, one of them would be able to pass point 4 and reach point 4, where it will add one more unit of energy and we will reach destination

Now we want  find minimum energy required at start to reach final destination.

Comment: (1) Traveling back to source costs 0 energy each iteration? (2) Can we revisit some destination?

Comment: @amit No you can only move forward through each point

Comment: @amit You need not move back to source , continue from latest point you visited

Comment: I really don't understand the question then, all nodes are in one dimensional line? The cost of energy is to "enter" a point, not to "travel" it?

Comment: isn't the answer just minus the smalles amount you will have during the path if you start with zero?

Comment: @amit Yes to enter a particular point you need to pay some energy and in back you get some energy as proit for visiting that point.

Comment: @JohanLundberg No we want minimum energy. you sure it will give be minimum?

Comment: @JohanLundberg Suppose you have 2 points one which take 3 units and give 0 units and same is other point. Then your solution wont pass

Comment: Is this problem from an online judge? It would be easier to understand if you could point us to the source of your question.

Comment: And you can skip/enter any point as you'd like - but has to follow the order of the points given (cannot enter point 3 before point 2)?

Comment: @amit Yes all points are sorted according to distance from origin  and you can't skip any point

Comment: @NikunjBanka It was an interview question. So sorry

Comment: why would I skip any point?

Comment: @JohanLundberg: One reason not to enter a point would be requirement exceeding profit, but (still not from the question, but in a comment), `you can't skip any point`. Which, assuming `energy` may not drop below zero, leaves open whether the requirement has to be met before or after collecting profit, or both. Oh, wait, I'm _assuming_ `require` to imply _consume_ …

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged your question as dynamic programming. But I think this is more of an adhoc problem with a simple O(n) solution. Start solving the problem from reverse. For the given problem with N=5 points:

To reach the destination, there must be atleast 1 unit of energy at the 5th point. Now suppose you enter the fifth point with `x` units of energy, then you can find the minimum value of x  through the equation:

> x - 1 + 2 >= 1 
>   implies  x>=0 
>   But minimum value of x should be 1 to reach the 5th point itself. Hence x = 1.

So you must have a minimum of 1 unit of energy while entering the 5th point to reach the final destination. Similarly we can find the minimum value of energy that would be needed on entering the fourth point as follows:

> x - 5 + 0 >= 1 
>   implies x >= 6

Thus to reach the destination point you will need atleast 6 units of energy when you enter point 4.

Continuing in this fashion you can find the minimum amount of energy that will be needed when you enter the first point. And that will be the required answer.

The following [working java code](https://ideone.com/dM0asP) implements this:

```
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            req[i] = sc.nextInt();
            profit[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        int minReq = 1;
        for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--){
            int minEnter = minReq+req[i]-profit[i];
            minEnter = Math.max(minEnter, req[i]);
            minReq = minEnter;
        }

        System.out.println(minReq);
```

Comment: @greybeard So is the solution correct according to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
         int[] arr = { 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 2, 6, 7, 6, 8, 9 };

         int[] ar = new int[arr.Length];
         int step = 1;
         ar[arr.Length - 1] = -1;

         for (int i = arr.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
         {
             if (arr[i] == 0)
                 ar[i] = -1;
             else if (arr[i] >= step)
                 ar[i] = 1;
             else 
             {
                 int min = int.MaxValue;
                 for (int j = 1; j <=arr[i]; j++)
                 {
                     if (ar[i+j]<  min && ar[i+j]>0)
                         min = ar[i+j];
                 }
                 ar[i] =min+ 1;
             }
             step++;
             }
         Console.WriteLine(ar[0]);
```